# How to access the class using include/require using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

I set up all the basic setup for Codeigniter Framework.

My Code:

controllers/index.php:

```
include "file_name.php"; //In my case APPPATH . "controllers/user/user_data.php"
```

controllers/user/file_name.php: //In my case controllers/user/user_data.php

```
<?php 

    echo "Welcome";

    class File_name 
    {
        function index()
        {
            echo "this is index";
            # code...
        }
    }
```

Output: 
What I getting:

```
welcome
```

What I need:

```
welcome this is index
```

My problem is I have file_path instead of file_name in include, so I am unable to create Object for the file.?

Comment: `include "file_name.php"; (new File_name())->index();`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Why shouldn't be able to create a object? Also what do you mean with: `I have file_path instead of file_name in include`  ?

Comment: see the comment I gave, That is I have in file_name.php

Comment: I see the word "controller" and `index()`. This tells me you're using some type of framework, CI maybe? You have answers below, by the way.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear what you're asking. (Unclear what you even want, and if you're using some type of framework also).

Comment: Yes, CodeIgniter Framework..

Comment: That ^ makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: People have posted answers below. If none of them worked for you, you should tell them why. As far as I'm concerned, it's still unclear what problem you're having. *Good luck*.

Comment: Actually the fault of my coding is my class name and my file name is different. Thanks for info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.php file:

```
include "file_name.php";
$file_name_obj = new File_Name();
$file_name_obj->index();
```

In your file_name.php file change:

```
function index()
```

to:

```
public function index ()
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `include` or `require` before instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Welcome ";
$fileName = new File_name();
$fileName->index();
```

Comment: Maybe you want to explain a little bit what you did here, so that OP know's what you wrote here

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to include a file, be sure to remember that your using a framework, CI. the proper way of including a file using codeigniter is using the "$this->load->view('name of file');" method, because , there are instance that using the include cause an error because it use preferably for pure php style not framework style.